# Zoho Books API: Include customer custom fields in api response

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

When getting a single invoice via `zohoapis.com/books/v3/invoices/:invoiceId`, the response includes custom fields of the customer under the key `customer_custom_fields`.

However, when getting a creditnote `zohoapis.com/books/v3/creditnotes/:creditNoteId` these customer_custom_fields are missing.

I wonder why this is and if there is a setting that allows including the customer custom fields in the creditnotes response.